# Odd behaviour in Django web app

Tags: javascript, html, django, supervisord

I've come across a strange bug in my Django application that has baffled me for the last few days.

Basically one of my dynamic templates stops rendering on the staging server. Everything works fine locally and when push to my staging server all seems fine however, after clicking around a few pages and then navigating back to one of the pages with this template it has suddenly disappeared. If i restart the supervisor processes the template reappears but then disappears again after navigating to other pages.

The weird thing is it's not consistent when it disappears. Sometimes it takes a few times navigating to other pages to disappear.

The template itself has dynamically generated content however even the container divs are not appearing so this leads me to believe that this is not a context error.

Another point about it is that if i stop my supervisor processes and run ./manage.py runserver instead, the problem doesn't seem to happen.

The things i've tried:

- I've used django-template-repl to load the url and view the context
  the template receives, all the data i expect to be rendered appears to be there.

Any help would be much appreciated, any tips on where to look next.

the view thats rendered:

```
def list(request):
projects = Project.objects.active()

order = request.GET.get('order', 'popular')
projects = projects.ordered_by(order)

search_q = request.GET.get('search_q')
if search_q:
    project_query_terms = ['title', 'short_description', 'who_description']
    username_query_terms = [
            'user__userprofile__first_name',
            'user__userprofile__last_name']
    project_query = create_query(search_q, project_query_terms)
    username_query = create_query(search_q, username_query_terms) & Q(
                           name_is_visible__exact=True)
    projects = projects.filter(project_query | username_query)
if request.GET.get('sector'):
    projects = projects.filter(sector__id=request.GET['sector'])

if request.GET.get('location'):
    projects = projects.filter(
            location=request.GET['location'],
            location_public=True)

form = ProjectFilterForm
form = (form(request.GET, projects=projects)
        if request.GET else form(projects=projects))
paginator = Paginator(projects, 9)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    projects = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    projects = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    projects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

amounts_by_project = Need.objects.amounts_by_project()
amounts_raised_by_project =        MoneyDonation.objects.amounts_raised_by_project()

context = {
    'body_id': 'project-list',
    'projects': projects,
    'form': form,
    'order': order,
    'amounts_by_project': amounts_by_project,
    'amounts_raised_by_project': amounts_raised_by_project,
}

template = "_projects-content" if request.is_ajax() else "projects"
template = "projects/" + template + ".html"

return render(request, template, context)
```

the projects-projects.html template

```
    {% extends 'projects/__base.html' %}
  {% load image_tags staticfiles projects %}

{% block content %}
  {% include 'projects/_projects-content.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
  FCC.drawDonuts('.col-project');
  jQuery(function updateWithFilters($){
    function queryWithParams() {
      var getParams = '';
      $('#project-filter-form select').each(function(i) {
        getParams += (i === 0) ? '?' : '&';
        getParams += this.name + '=' + $(this).children('option:selected')[0].value;
      });
      $.get({% url 'projects' %} + getParams, function(res){
        $("#projects-content").html(res);
        updateWithFilters($);
        FCC.drawDonuts('.col-project');
      });
    }
    $('#project-filter-form select').change(function(e){
      queryWithParams();
    });
    $('#reset-filters').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#project-filter-form select option:selected').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('selected', false);
        queryWithParams();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

the _projects-content.html

```
<div id='projects-content'>
  {% include 'projects/_projects-filters.html' %}
  {% include 'projects/_projects-projects.html' %}
</div>
```

the _projects-projects.html

```
<section class="section hp-projects">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 sub-header">
        <sub-header>
          <h2>Browse all projects</h2>
        </sub-header>
      </div>
      {% if not projects %}
        <p>No projects match your search.</p>
      {% endif %}
      {% for project in projects %}
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          {% include '_project-thumbnail.html' %}
      </div><!--col-->
      {% endfor %}
    </div><!--row-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        {% with projects as collection %}
          {% include 'pagination.html' %}
        {% endwith %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--container-->
</section>
```

_project-thumbnail.html

```
{% load total staticfiles projects %}
<div class="project-container">
  <header>
    <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.id %}" class="project">
      <h5 class="project-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
    </a>
  </header>
  <figure>
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.id %}" class="project">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ project.profile_image }}" alt="project image" />
      </a>
    </div>
  <figcaption>{{ project.short_description }}</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <div class="row three-donuts">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      {% include "projects/_project-donate-thumbnail.html" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      {% include "projects/_project-volunteer-thumbnail.html" %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--box-container-->
```

_project-donate-thumbnail.html is the template that is not rendering after navigating to another page
here's the content of the file but as i said nothing inside this renders once you navigate away from this page after a fresh server restart.
**however the _project-volunteer-thumbnail stays completely fine.** It is just the donate-thumnail that disappears.

_project-donate-thumbnail.html

```
<div id="project-{{ project.id }}-donate" class="col-project this-project-donate">
  <span class="percentage">
    {% if project.donate_aim %}
      {{ project.donate_percent }}% 
    {% endif %}
  </span>
</div>
<div class="equation">
 £{{ project.donate_status }}
<span class="desired-amount">/ £{{ project.donate_aim }}</span>
</div>
<div class="button-link-wrapper">
  {% if project.donate_aim %}
    <a href="{% url 'project_donate' project.id %}" class="button graph-button donate">donate</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="button graph-button donate deactivated">donate</span>
  {% endif %}

</div>
```

again any tips on where to look next would be helpful